# WooCommerce custom billing fields on email address

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, editor

I want to add the custom billing fields that I added with the WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor plugin into the email that it's sent to the customer:

I added the custom num_int field:
[image]

And tried to add it with the woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address filter:
This is the code I used:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', array($this, 'woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address'), 10, 2);

function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address( $address , $WC_Order )
{

    $address = array(
        'first_name'    => 'Nombre: ' . $WC_Order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $address['last_name'],
        'address_1'     => 'Dirección: ' . $WC_Order->billing_address_1,
        'address_2'     => 'Colonia: ' . $WC_Order->billing_address_2,
        'city'          => 'Ciudad: ' . $WC_Order->billing_city,
        'state'         => 'Estado: ' . $WC_Order->billing_state,
        'postcode'      => 'Código Postal: ' . $WC_Order->billing_postcode,

        //this is the custom field i want to add
        'num_int'       => 'Num. Interior: ' . $WC_Order->billing_num_int,

    );

    return $address;

}
```

But it won't show on the email:

[image]

Comment: Try **$WC_Order->num_int**

Comment: @Aparna_29 It didn't work, but if I use something like:
` 'address_2'     => 'Colonia: ' . $WC_Order->num_int `
Its works but that's not the way i want to show the billing address

Comment: Have you tried following code   **'num_int'       => 'Num. Interior: ' . $WC_Order->num_int**  instead  of
        **'num_int'       => 'Num. Interior: ' . $WC_Order->billing_num_int**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work using this code:

I'm using a php class to make an organized workflow so don't mind the **public** on functions...

First I register my filters like this:

```
public function registerFilters()
{
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', array($this, 'woo_new_default_address_fields'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', array($this, 'woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', array($this, 'myFunction'), 10, 2);
    add_filter('woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', array($this, 'mySecondFunction'), 10, 2);

    return $this;
}
```

With this function I can add/register the custom fields to make them by default, this way it will show on the plugin section with the letters on purple (shown in the screenshot at the top of the page):

```
public function woo_new_default_address_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['colonia'] = array(

        'label' => __( 'Colonia', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),

    );
    $fields['num_int'] = array(

        'label' => __( 'Num. Interior', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),

    );
    $fields['num_ext'] = array(

        'label' => __( 'Num. Exterior', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),

    );
    $fields['municipio'] = array(

        'label' => __( 'Municipio', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),

    );
    $fields['reference'] = array(

        'label' => __( 'Referencias', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),

    );

    $order = array(
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "colonia",
        "num_int",
        "num_ext",
        "municipio",
        "reference",
        "company",
        "country",
        "address_1",
        "address_2",
        "city",
        "state",
        "postcode"
    );

    foreach($order as $field) {

        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields[$field];

    }

    $fields = $ordered_fields;

    return $fields;
}
```

Then I add them to the formatted billing address for the emails:

```
public function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address( $address , $WC_Order )
{

    $address = array(
        'first_name'    => 'Nombre: ' . $WC_Order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $address['last_name'],
        'address_1'     => 'Dirección: ' . $WC_Order->billing_address_1,
        'colonia'     => 'Colonia: ' . $WC_Order->billing_colonia,
        'num_ext'       => 'Num. Exterior: ' . $WC_Order->billing_num_ext,
        'num_int'       => 'Num. Interior: ' . $WC_Order->billing_num_int,
        'reference'     => 'Referencias: ' . $WC_Order->billing_reference,
        'city'          => 'Ciudad: ' . $WC_Order->billing_city,
        'state'         => 'Estado: ' . $WC_Order->billing_state,
        'municipio'     => 'Municipio: ' . $WC_Order->billing_municipio,
        'postcode'      => 'Código Postal: ' . $WC_Order->billing_postcode,


    );

    return $address;

}
```

Here I replace/add my custom fields into the address for them to be used on the formatted billing address:

```
public function myFunction( $address, $args )
{
    $address['{colonia}'] = $args['colonia'];
    $address['{num_int}'] = $args['num_int'];
    $address['{num_ext}'] = $args['num_ext'];
    $address['{municipio}'] = $args['municipio'];
    $address['{reference}'] = $args['reference'];
    return $address;
}
```

And then I replace/add them on how it will be shown:

```
public function mySecondFunction($formats)
{
    foreach($formats as $key => $value) :
        $formats[$key] .= "\n\n{colonia}";
        $formats[$key] .= "\n\n{num_int}";
        $formats[$key] .= "\n\n{num_ext}";
        $formats[$key] .= "\n\n{municipio}";
        $formats[$key] .= "\n\n{reference}";
    endforeach;

    return $formats;
}
```

I hope you can all understand me, I'm not an expert :)